# Typescript does not trust that a property will definitely be created in an object

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have the following Typescript code which I'm trying to fit the type `Data` with at least a `mainData` property.

```
interface Data {
    [K: string]: string
    mainData: string
}

function getDataObj(dynamicData: string[]): Data {
    return dynamicData.reduce((res, val) => ({
        ...res,
        [val]: 'some stuff'
    }), {})
}

// In the actual app, the dynamicData are coming dynamically and are not hardcoded like so in this example
const dynamicData = ['dataA', 'dataB', 'mainData']

const dataObj: Data = getDataObj(dynamicData)
```

However, the code above will give me the following error:

```
Property 'mainData' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Data'.(2741)
input.ts(3, 5): 'mainData' is declared here
```

The problem is that Typescript doesn't trust that `mainData` will definitely exist in the `dynamicData` parameter array. However, in my case, the `mainData` property will definitely exist on the array but I just want to add it to the Data interface for better code completion.

Here's the snippet on [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHZBvAUMg5AbQGkAuZAZzClAHMBdC62kO-QgWzlHU2Zr1cAX1y4YAVxAIwwAPYhkdCGD5wA8gCMAVgAoAJgE8QcTsARqBrOkQYBKCmpwcCUFRKiKjJsxYxwAOjd9CSRdXTdKABpkADc4ABs7ZABeAD5kXTxCHOQA-Miol1yieISmZABySjlOFGoJGBhK4uE7GOw2kTEAeh7kAElFMAALFEQwCUTkOAAHWZjRlG9Tcyc4N2QEWvpkFd9EhMMZkH0ZzZA5MGQRjf1t-QgzhOAAa3q5ZFBkUeBKZAgAA9TLMEhBcNsQNQ9sZVn5MKliJV9P4AIKVGLI-wAIQxVW4vH8lQYYkh0JRmC02kc-kRylU-ipBlhvjUdiAA).

What else can I do so that Typescript will trust that I will have `mainData` created as one the properties in the `Data` object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like in order for typescript to be able to know that a certain item will be in any array, you have to assert, via a type, that that value will be present. For instance, like so:

```js
interface Data {
    [K: string]: string
    mainData: string
}

const getDataObj_ = <T extends string>(dynamicData: ['mainData', ...T[]]): Data => dynamicData.reduce((p, c) => ({
    ...p,
    [c]: 'some stuff',
} as { [key in T | 'mainData']: string }), {} as { [key in T | 'mainData']: string });

// In the actual app, the dynamicData are coming dynamically and are not hardcoded like so in this example
const dynamicData: ['mainData', ...string[]] = ['mainData', 'dataA', 'dataB']

const dataObj: Data = getDataObj_(dynamicData)
```

Comment: using as violates type safety and should not be used

Comment: @andrèscoronado `as` is often the only way around typing issues and I don't think you'll be able to avoid it here without manually setting `mainData` to some invalid value

Comment: if you declare an interface with an attribute that is required you always want to respect that, that's why the mistake here is in the reduction function returning an empty object not implementing the Data interface. To implement that interface with an object means that the `mainData` attribute must be there.  One trick would be modify the interface with a union type on the key value so that `[K: string | 'mainData']: string`. You are in general right though, but in this particular case there are many workarounds that preserve type safety

Comment: @andrèscoronado I think your stretching a bit to try and say that this breaks type safety; the input type must contain `'mainData'`, as asserted by the type. The code therefore demands that this key will be on the return type. We have to do `as` in order to get Typescript to realise that, but clearly the code cannot return anything else. I'd rather make the assertion that the input data must be correct in containing the correct key; if it doesn't, then we have no business trying to correct the input data by adding the key as the `reduce` default.

Comment: I see your point, and you are right. What if  `dynamicData` has no `mainData` field, is the output of the reduce function implementing `Data` interface as function signature declares? (in your answer that input would not be accepted, and the as is safe i see! )

Answer (score 2):

try this way, in the reduce function add `{mainData: ''}` as initial value.

```
interface Data {
    [K: string]: string;
    mainData: string;

}

function getDataObj(dynamicData: string[]): Data {
    return dynamicData.reduce((res, val) => ({
        ...res,
        [val]: 'some stuff'
    }), {mainData: ''})
}

// In the actual app, the dynamicData are coming dynamically and are not hardcoded like so in this example
const dynamicData = ['dataA', 'dataB', 'mainData'];

const dataObj: Data = getDataObj(dynamicData);
console.log(dataObj);
```